# Why is spring being installed on my production server?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano, bundler, rbenv

I have a Gemfile with spring defined in `:development` like so:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

# Rake and rails
gem 'rake', '~> 10.4.2'
gem 'rails', '4.1.13'

group :production do
  gem 'unicorn', '~> 4.8.3'
end

group :development, :staging do
  gem 'spring'
end
```

However it's being installed on the server whenever I deploy.
The command which is issued by capistrano looks like this: `cd /home/app_user/apps/ag/releases/20150921131835 && bundle install --gemfile /home/app_user/apps/ag/releases/20150921131835/Gemfile --path /home/app_user/apps/ag/shared/bundle --deployment --without development test`

I do not understand why? How can I get rid of spring?

My bundler version is 1.10.6

Comment: You haven't specified the `staging` group in `without` flag, therefore it is also installed

Comment: Pray tell, what does your `config/deploy/production.rb` file look like? Your `config/deploy.rb` file as well.. Capistrano usually does a good production deployment out of the box with Rails, not sure why yours has gone belly up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Yury Lebedev mentioned in a comment, you haven't excluded the `staging` group in the `without` flag, therefore gems defined as `staging` also installed (including `spree` in your case).